# How to check data type inside pig UDF

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, udf

I am new to Pig scripting.

I want to write a filter udf irrespective of data type of columns.

```
iput_data = load data '/emp.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (empid int, name chararray);

output = FILTER input_data by FilterUDF(empid);//data type is int

input_data1 = load data '/dept.csv' using pigStorage(',') as (deptid chararray, deptname chararray);

output1 = FILTER input_data by FilterUDF(deptid); //data type is chararray
```

Now,inside PigUdf, how to identify data type of input parameter? (i.e. data type of input.get(0) )

```
import org.apache.pig.FilterFunc;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;


public class FilterUDF extends FilterFunc {

    public Boolean exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        //How to check data type inside UDF
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the getType() method to find the data type of individual elements of the tuple. See this [link](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/data/Tuple.html)

Something like

```
if (input.getType(0) == INTEGER) {
    // Do something here
}
```

Hope this helps.